# Is it possible to turn off certain Excel functions related to conditional formatting and data validations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, data-validation

I have come across a monstrosity of an Excel, while it does not make any sense in my opinion to have this Excel. Some of my colleagues at this large corporate are extremely fond of using it. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to make any changes to the Excel other than the sheets that are unlocked to me.

Despite me having a laptop with sufficient memory (32GB) and a normal AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650U CPU, I am having great difficulties editing the Excel as constantly everything seems to be stuck. I have unlocked the Excel and tried to analyse why the Excel is so slow and I think I have found the problem. In my opinion it is because of the volatile functions that they use in the data validation and extreme amounts of conditional formatting.

Therefore my obvious question, is there a solution to turn off conditional formatting and data validation temporarily and enable them when I close the Excel prior to sending them to my colleagues? Or am I hopeless and I have to ask the company to buy a new computer just for this Excel?

PS: if it matters, I am using Office 365 and I have disabled all plugins. Even in safe mode it is extremely slow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can pause conditional formatting, but this requires the permission to add conditional formatting rules. Do you have this permission?

Comment: I am able to edit the conditional formatting rules, however as the conditional formatting is relatively complex and not all located in one area, but at many different ranges and across different sheets. I am having trouble to "revert everything back" if I were to edit them.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate one method, I've created a random array and a single conditional formatting rule:

[image]

If I can't edit or remove the other rules, but I can add a rule on each sheet. then if I want to disable other rules temporarily, I can add this rule above the existing rule. It's a simple formula that evaluates to True when the word pause is entered in cell A1. The rule has no changes to the formatting.

[image]

Note that "Stop if True" is checked. The Applies To range should cover the union of the ranges of any other rules.

The result is that when I enter "pause" in cell A1, this rule will evaluate to TRUE, and no further rules will be executed.

[image]